# Reading std::cin hangs if no pipe is provided

Tags: c++, istream

I have a function of the general form

```
void readStuff(std::istream& input){
    int var;
    while(input>>var){
        //... do stuff
    }
}
```

where input is passed as either std::cin or std::ifstream, depending on whether a command line option -c is set. Reading from file

```
myprog file.txt
```

works fine. If std::cin is used,

```
cat file.txt | myprog -c
```

that works fine as well. However, it hangs if the user tries

```
myprog -c
```

How can I handle this case from within my code? I've tried checking ifstream's flags, but in all cases they are 0 except for ifstream.good().

Comment: It isn't hanging; it is just waiting for input.

Comment: Well yes, but there won't be any...

Comment: This is normal behavior of all commands. Try executing just `cat` on your terminal, you'll see that it waits for input until you send an EOF.

Comment: So there's no way to do this from within my code?

Comment: You can use [isatty](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html) to check if your program was piped or is reading input from the terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program isn't hanging; `cin` is just waiting for input from the terminal.

When you piped `cat` command's `stdout` into your program's `stdin`, there was an `EOF` in your `stdin`. This would cause the `eof` flag to be set which in turn would cause `while(input>>var)` to fail; hence exiting the loop.

When you execute your program directly from the terminal, `cin` keeps waiting for input from the terminal until the input stream is closed. You can exit your program by sending an `EOF` through the terminal which will close the input stream which in turn will break the loop in your code.

If you want your program to exit if it is not in a pipe, you can check using [isatty](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html) on POSIX systems and [_isatty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f4s0ddew.aspx) on Windows.